# Installing imagick on CentOS 7 with XAMPP and PHP 7

Tags: php, apache, xampp, imagick

I have a local machine with Ubuntu, Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.0

I could install imagick easily using apt-get, but I can't seem to be able to do it on CentOS with XAMPP.

I tried many things including:

yum install php70w-pecl-imagick-devel.x86_64

pecl install imagick

Copying the imagick.so file to the modules directory

Adding extension=imagick.so to /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini and restarting

But the module simply isn't being loaded!

I keep on getting Class 'Imagick' not found in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Try with CMD or SSH or PuTTY

Once you have enabled the EPEL repository, install ImageMagick with dnf command.

```
dnf install -y ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
```

PHP Imagick is a native PHP extension to create and modify bitmap images using the ImageMagick API.

```
dnf install -y php php-devel php-pear make
```

Now, install PHP Imagick with pecl command.

```
pecl install imagick

Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] :
```

just press Enter; do not type a prefix (that is, allow autodetect).

Add the extension into the php.ini file.

```
echo "extension=imagick.so" > /etc/php.d/20-imagick.ini
```

Restart the Apache web service to take an effect of newly installed PHP extension.

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

List the complied modules to see if PHP Imagick is installed and available.

```
php -m
```